# Changing code from an while loop to array_shift

Tags: php

I have a DB with categories and subcategories and I want to find the original parent of a subcategory. For example if I have C1->C2->C3->C4 where C1 is the original parent, I want to find the id of C1, knowing the id of C4. I have succeded to find it using an if statement with a while loop but I was told to change it to a array_shift() because the while would be very slow when there will be a lot of data going through it. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to change the code from while to array_shift, not even where to start. This is what I have right now:

```
        $sql = "SELECT `parent_id` FROM c_assoc WHERE c_id = $cToPutInto";
        $result = $conn -> query($sql);

        if($result -> num_rows > 0) {
            $parent = $result -> fetch_assoc()['parent_id'];
            $sql = "SELECT `parent_id` FROM c_assoc WHERE c_id = $parent";
            $result = $conn -> query($sql);
            while ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
                $parent = $result -> fetch_assoc()['parent_id'];
                $sql = "SELECT `parent_id` FROM c_assoc WHERE c_id = $parent";
                $result = $conn -> query($sql);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `$con` a `\PDO` object here?

Comment: if i understand , your code work fine with the while loop , is that true ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, yes it does!

Comment: @SimonBrahan, I am using MySQLi Object-Oriented. $conn comes from where I create the connection.

Comment: if you want , you can use Recursive CTE , it like a recursive query , at the end  , you will have the final parent . wanna some example ?

Comment: i still cannot what's the link between the loop and array_shift

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, I don't know either, this is why I have been doing some research and asking here because I cannot find a way to achieve the goal. I will look into Recursive CTE. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to go ask the `array_shift` advocate exactly what they're talking about. I don't think stack overflow can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that you can try :

Let's suppose you have a table categorie like :

```
   "id"|"parent_id"|"name"
    "1" |   NULL    | "PHP"
    "2" |   "1"     |"Symfony"
    "3" |   "1"     |"Laravel"
    "4" |   NULL    |"JAVA"
    "5" |   "4"     |"Spring"
    "6" |   "4"     |"JEE"
    "7" |   "2"     |"Command"
    "8" |   "2"     |"Request"
```

the root parent categorie has parent_id equal to null  , so you can mae a simple query to select the root parent without making while loop , like :

```
select * from (select name, id, @parent:=parent_id as parent from 
(select @parent:=8 ) a join (select * from categorie order by id desc) b
 where @parent=id) as res WHERE res.parent IS NULL
```

In your can , you can inject the id of the categorie you want (in my example , i'm using 8 value )

The result return :

```
|id|name|parent|
|  |    |      |
|1 |PHP | NULL |
```

Hope that help you.